# Green's function Laplace equation through Fourier space

Tags: fourier-transform, greens-function

\begin{align}
- \nabla^2 G(r) &= \delta(r) \\
G(r) &\rightarrow  0 \mbox{ as } r \rightarrow \infty
\end{align}
where $ r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$

In order to find the Green's function I take the Fourier transform
of the equation. This gives me

\begin{align}
\mathrm{k}^2 \hat{G}(\mathrm{k}) = 1 \tag{1}
\end{align}

where $\mathrm{k} = \sqrt{k_1^2 + k_2^2 + k_3^2} $

The idea is to divide the equation by $\mathrm{k}^2$ then take the back transform of the equation. This gives me the Green's function $G(r)$. However $\mathrm{k}$ can be equal to $0$. Implying equation $(1)$ to be false.

The question is why is the Green's function $G(r)$ found by this method correct?

Comment: If $k=0$ in equation one the statement says $0  = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\mathscr{F}\{\nabla^2 G\}(\vec k)=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\nabla^2G(\vec r)e^{i\vec k\cdot\vec r}\,dx\,dy\,dz=-k^2\mathscr{F}\{G(\vec r)\}=-1$$

Hence,

$$\mathscr{F}\{G\}(\vec k)=\frac{1}{ k^2}$$

for $k\ne 0$.  Since the value of the integral is independent of the value of the integrand at a single point, the value of  $\mathscr{F}\{G\}(\vec k=0)$ is irrelevant.  Proceeding, we find

$$\begin{align}
G(\vec r)&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\iiint_{\mathscr{R}^3}\frac{e^{-i\vec k\cdot\vec r}}{k^2}\,dk_x\,dk_y\,dk_z\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi )^3}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-i kr\cos(\theta)}\,\sin(\theta)\,dk\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-i kr\cos(\theta)}\,\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{2\sin(kr)}{kr}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi r}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. As I understand it you argue that the value F(G)(k=0) is irrelevant. Since you show the integral to be exactly $\frac{1}{4 \pi r}$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Yes, indeed; the value $\mathscr{F}\{G\}(\vec k=0)$ is not relevant to the value of its (inverse) Fourier Transform.